# How to reset SVN?

Tags: svn

I want to test path-based authorization in SVN. I am working on a server, which is not administrated by me, so I can't tell what was done to enable SVN.

I presume that I have to restart the server running the SVN after modifying certain files. The problem is that I don't know how to do it.

When I run ps aux, there is no apache2 nor svnserve process. There is not even one process having SVN in its name. What to do now?

How is it possible that SVN works? I use svn+ssh to transfer data so I am sure it works. But there are no processes somehow connected to SVN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`svn+ssh` uses SSH as the transport, it doesn't go over HTTP(S) and doesn't use apache2.

More importantly, svn+ssh is an "on demand" transport there is no persistent daemon that speaks the SVN protocol at all. Your client first connects to the server via SSH, then it asks the SSH server to start a new 'svnserve' process just for this session. As a result the SVN server-side configuration will be re-read every time.

(The sshd service itself might have the full svnserve command line configured somewhere, e.g. in sshd_config or in the user's authorized_keys file. This usually doesn't need to be changed.)

Comment: Thank you very much, that clears a lot! So now I understand that all I need to do in order to enable path-based authorization is to point to the file with config in svnserve.conf.